# Converting pretrained saved model from NCHW to NHWC to make it compatible for Tensorflow Lite

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have converted a model from PyTorch to Keras and used the backend to extract the tensorflow graph. Since the data format for PyTorch was NCHW, the model extracted and saved is also that. While converting the model to TFLite, due to the format being NCHW, it cannot get converted. Is there a way to convert the whole graph into NHCW?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to have a graph with the data-format matched to TFLite for faster inference. One approach is to manually insert transpose ops into the graph, like this example:
[How to convert the CIFAR10 tutorial to NCHW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153624/how-to-convert-the-cifar10-tutorial-to-nchw)

```
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

with tf.Session(config=config) as session:

    kernel = tf.ones(shape=[5, 5, 3, 64])
    images = tf.ones(shape=[64,24,24,3])

    imgs = tf.transpose(images, [0, 3, 1, 2]) # NHWC -> NCHW
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(imgs, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME', data_format = 'NCHW')
    conv = tf.transpose(conv, [0, 2, 3, 1]) # NCHW -> NHWC

    print("conv=",conv.eval())
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to convert a NCHW graph to NHWC; you have to start with a NHWC graph to train at the very beginning, if later you want to run with TF lite.