# Is there any way that can convert a data format of .pb file from NCHW into NHWC?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I have a CNN model which was trained in Pytorch based on the data format **N(batch) x C(channel) x H(height) x W(width)**. I saved the pre-trained model as **model.pth**. Afterward, I converted the pre-trained model from **model.pth -> model.onnx** by using existing function:

```py
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "model.onnx")
```

And then, I converted this **model.onnx -> model.pb** by the module below:

```py
import onnx
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare 

model_onnx = onnx.load('model.onnx')
tf_rep = prepare(model_onnx)
tf_rep.export_graph('model.pb')
```

The problem is: I want to utilize this model.pb on a CPU device, which needs a **NHWC** data format. However, my model is based on NCHW data format. Is there any method that can convert the data format of this model.pb from NCHW into NHWC?

Comment: Please clarify your question, see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my question. Is it better? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you are in a tough spot.

Long answer, it's difficult yet possible. What makes your problem difficult is **your graph is already trained**. It is inefficient, yet easier to convert NCHW->NHWC while you create the training graph. See similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153976/10681163) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565635/10681163).

Now to your answer, you'll have to overload conv2D operator with custom convolution operator. Here is a pseudo code to get started.

```
   tensor Conv2D(X, W, B) {
     int perm[] = {0, 3, 1, 2};
     X = transposeTensor(X, perm);
     W = transposeTensor(W, perm);
     Y = Conv2D_orig(X, W, B, ...) ;
     perm = {0, 2, 3, 1};
     return transposeTensor(Y, perm);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just transpose the input tensors? e.g. `input.transpose(1,2).transpose(2,3)` ?

```
>>> torch.randn( (3,3,3,3), names=['n','c','h','w']).transpose(1,2).transpose(2,3).names
('n', 'h', 'w', 'c')
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean before training in Pytorch? Thanks for the answer, any advice helps!

Comment: yes... on any inputs, whether training data and evaluation data. Any inputs that have an incompatible dimensions.

Comment: Doesn't torch.nn only use channel first as data format i.e. NCHW in this case? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's right. Your input data can be converted but I'm not sure what model you're trying to run. You can follow work to support channel last here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/28619

Comment: I'm using customized model. I'll try to follow the github issue you mentioned. Thanks for helping again.